# Mockito mocked method is returning NULL

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito and have tried to mock the below test class.
Here the main class method createNewId() is getting the object by hitting dao class 'memberDao.findNext()'.
I am trying to mock 'memberDao.findNext()' and return the object as shown in below code but it is returning as NULL.

**ALSO how to write Test for void method which is "memberDao.delete(newId.getId());"**
Need to implement this after this line "when(memberDao.findNext()).thenReturn(id);"

Please let me know what am i doing wrong.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MemberTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    private Member member;
    @Mock
    private MemberDao memberDao;

    @Test
    public void createId() throws Exception
    {
        MembersIdDto id = new MembersIdDto();
        id.setId("967405286");
        when(memberDao.findNext()).thenReturn(id);
        verify(member).createNewId().contains("967405286");
    }


    public class Member {
    @Resource
    MemberDao memberDao;

    public String createNewId()
    {
        MembersIdDto newId = memberDao.findNext();   
        Assert.notNull(newId, "newId is empty");
        String id = newId.getId();
        memberDao.delete(newId.getId());
        return id;
    }
    }
```

memberDao.findNext() is the line i am trying to mock.

Error is : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newId is empty

```
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
at Member.createNewId() (Member.java:20)
```

// Line 20 is "Assert.notNull(newId, "newId is empty");"

Comment: What type is ```manager``` of? Isn't this the class-under-test? I can not see any calls on production code in your ```@Test``` method.

Comment: Also note, that you either use ```@Mock``` to create mocks or you do it manually ```Mockito.mock(MemberDao.class)```. Doing it both is at least redundant.

Comment: oh! my bad. i have updated the code.. Its Member class and not MainClass ..

Comment: Cool, I posted a corresponding working example in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working example of your requirement could be:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MemberTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private Member member;
    @Mock
    private MemberDao memberDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void createId() throws Exception {
        MembersIdDto dto = new MembersIdDto();
        dto.setId("967405286");
        when(memberDao.findNext()).thenReturn(dto);

        assertThat(member.createNewId()).isEqualTo("967405286");
    }
}
```

…with the classes-under-test…

```
public class Member {
    @Resource
    MemberDao memberDao;

    public String createNewId() {
        return memberDao.findNext().getId();
    }
}
```

…and…

```
public class MemberDao {
    public MembersIdDto findNext() {
        return null; // or whatever
    }
}
```

…and…

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MembersIdDto {
    private String id;
}
```

By the way, I use the [AssertJ assertion framework](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) and with `member.createNewId()` you have now a real call on production code.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two instances of MemberDao. First MockitoJUnitRunner creates an instance, assigns it to the field `memberDao` and injects that instance into the Member object. Afterwards in the method `setUp` you create a new instance of the DAO and assign it to the field `memberDao`. Therefore the field `memberDao` is no longer the same as the Member's DAO. While you define behaviour on the field, the Member object is still using the first DAO that has no behaviour defined. Therefore `memberDao.findNext()` in `Member#createNewId` returns `null`.

Fortunately the solution is very simple: Delete the `setUp` method in your test.

Comment: This answer was more helpful to me in a roundabout way. In my case I was using the Spring `@MockBean` annotation and then ALSO (erroneously) instantiating it with `mock(MyClassName.class)`. So after removing the manual instantiation, it worked.